# Android XmlSax Parsor Error in Xml file

Tags: android, saxparser, saxparseexception

Error:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'build-tools;23.0.0 rc2' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9_-;.]+' for type 'segmentListType'.

This error i am getting when i compile my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of this error by removing `$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/23.0.0_rc2` and switch to `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"` or higher in your `build.gradle` file.